# LINQ - grouping by name to Dictionary<string, List<T>>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am building a library app. I have a list of Books where some of them have a duplicate name (there are few copies of the same book). I would like to convert the list to Dictionary>, where the string would be the name of a book, and the List would contain all the Book objects with this name.

I've managed to get this far:

```
var result  = queriedBooks
                .GroupBy(b => b.Name)
                .Where(g => g.Count() >= 1)
                .ToDictionary(b => b.Key, /// );
```

This is where I get stuck. I have no idea what to pass as a value. Intellisense does not help either, as there is no `Value` property available. I would like to avoid using anonymous objects, as each Book entry has many properties which I use in a view.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What about non-duplicate books? Do you want to include them too?

Comment: `b => b.ToList()` should work

Comment: Eh, `g.Count() >= 1` looks *redundant*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As an alternative you may want just `Lookup<String, Book>` instead of combersome `Dictionary<String, List<Book>>`:

```
   LookUp<String, Book> result = queriedBooks
     .ToLookup(book => book.Name);
```

In case of `Dictionary<String, List<Book>>`:

```
   var result = queriedBooks
     .GroupBy(book => book.Name) 
     .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key, chunk => chunk.ToList());
```

Please note that `.Where(g => g.Count() >= 1)` is *redundant*;

Comment: Thank you! I've decided to use `ToLookup` as it seems a more sufficient solution. But the thing I struggle at now is how to render a <Book> `Name` propertyin a View. Previously for a simple list of Books, I used @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)` and it worked. Do you possibly know how can I access this property while using Lookup? Tried `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault()` and this would give me the first pair, but I have no idea how to access the Book object and its properties inside. Thanks!

Comment: @Dandry: since `LookUp<String, Book>` implements `IEnumerable<IGrouping<String, Book>>` you, probably, want something like `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Key)` or alike; to obtain `Book` instances model => model.FirstOrDefault().Select(book => ...)` since `IGrouping<String, Book>` implements `IEnumerable<Book>`

Comment: Those somehow do not work. However, I've managed to get this working: `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().First().Name)`. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 6):

You should simply use `ToList()` like this:

```
.ToDictionary(b => b.Key, b => b.ToList());
```

Each group has a `Key` property which is the key. It also (the group) is an `IEnumerable<Book>` that represents the items in the group which is why `ToList()` works.

Answer (score 1):

try with `ToList` with `distinct` for example  In a table, a column may contain many duplicate values; and sometimes you only want to list the different (distinct) values.

```
var query  = queriedBooks
            .Distinct()
            .GroupBy(b => b.Name)
            .ToDictionary(b => b.Key, b.ToList() );
```

please don't use it `.Where(g => g.Count() >= 1)` it  is redundant